# Script will not copy files when run via task scheduler

Tags: python

I have a script utilizing shutil.copy2 to copy files from one folder to newly created folder that was created by the same script. When the script is run manually it works as expected; creating a new directory and copying files into it. When run via Task Scheduler in Windows it creates the directory and copies the first file but does not proceed to the next file.

I have read that the source file needs to be removed for the script to continue but that is false as I indicated the script runs successfully when run manually and keeps the file intact at the source.

I also cannot run the task with 'the highest privs.'

Please help as I am about to lose my sh!t.

I have included my original version that utilizes a FOR loop.

I also included a crude copy script that uses shutil.copy2 and DOES work via Task Scheduler.

```
import shutil
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
path = r"\\xxxx\xxx_Share\gis\~ SAP IMPORTS" + "/" + today
os.mkdir(path)
src_path = r"\\xxxx\xxx_Share\SAPextracts"
dst_path = path

while os.listdir(src_path):
  file = os.listdir(src_path)[0]
  src_file = src_path + "/" + file
  dst_file = dst_path + "/" + file
  if not file.startswith('arch'):
    start = int(time.strftime("%S", time.localtime(time.time())))
    shutil.copy2(src_file, dst_file)
    end = int(time.strftime("%S", time.localtime(time.time())))
    time_taken = int(end - start)
    log_message = f"{datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()} - {src_file} COPIED TO {dst_file} IN {time_taken}"
    print(log_message)
    with open('transfer_log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(log_message + '\n')
```

First version.

```
import shutil
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
path = r"\\xxxx\xxx_Share\gis\~ SAP IMPORTS" + "/" + today
os.mkdir(path)
src_path = r"\\xxxx\xxx_Share\SAPextracts"
dst_path = path

for file in os.listdir(src_path):
  src_file = src_path + "/" + file
  dst_file = dst_path + "/" + file
  if not file.startswith('arch'):
    start = int(time.strftime("%S", time.localtime(time.time())))
    shutil.copy2(src_file, dst_file)
    end = int(time.strftime("%S", time.localtime(time.time())))
    time_taken = int(end - start)
    log_message = f"{datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()} - {src_file} COPIED TO {dst_file} IN {time_taken}"
    print(log_message)
    with open('transfer_log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(log_message + '\n')
```

Crude version that works.

```
import shutil
import os
# import arcpy
 
src = r'\\xxxx\xxx_Share\SAPextracts'
trg = r'\\xxxx\xxx_Share\gis\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS'
 

files = ['GISDEVICES.TXT', 'GISHYD.TXT', 'GISPREMISE.TXT', 'GISMETERS.TXT', 'GISCUST.TXT', 'GISINSTALL.TXT', 'GISLEDCOP.TXT']

def removefiles():
    
    for fname in files:
    
        print(fname)     
        os.remove(os.path.join(trg,fname))
    

def copyfiles():
    
     for ffname in files:
     
         print(ffname)     
         shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src,ffname), trg)
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
     removefiles()
     copyfiles()
```

Comment: You reshared the real file paths when you added the crude version.

Comment: In general, using raw string manipulation to manage paths is a bad idea. Try using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or `os.path.join` instead (as you did in the crude version).

Comment: I will give that a try as time permits. Thank you @MatBailie